# Adonis js: Переименование системных папок

Tags: adonis.js

У меня есть вопрос по поводу фреймворка adonis js - дело в том, что мне нужно переименовать папку `resources` в `src` и папку в ней же `views` в `pages` так, чтобы он видел файлы рендеринга `*.edge` и рендерил страницы. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих поисков ответа, я наконец-то нашёл ответ на свой вопрос: Оказывается есть для этих целей файл `adonisrc.json`. В него надо добавить этот код:

```
{
  "typescript": true,
  "directories": {
    "config": "config",
    "public": "public",
    "contracts": "contracts",
    "providers": "providers",
    "database": "database",
    "migrations": "database/migrations",
    "seeds": "database/seeders",
    "resources": "src",
    "views": "src/pages",
    "start": "start",
    "tmp": "tmp",
    "tests": "tests"
  }
}
```

Каждый ключ объекта отвечает за директорию папки, которая должна быть.
Единственное остаётся поменять пути в других файлах и в webpack.